# Should you include aberration effects during low Earth orbit observations?

Tags: observational-astronomy, orbit, amateur-observing, orbital-mechanics

I am working on calibration of some observations of low Earth orbit satellites and I am wondering should I include aberration effects? My logic is that diurnal aberration would have neglegible magnitude for such low orbit (I have at best 2-3 arcsecs of precision) and annual aberration does not have any effect, because satellites are rotating around a Sun together with Earth. Is my logic correct or magnitudes of aberration effects are bigger than I think?

Comment: Low Earth satellite speeds are about 8 km/s.  The Earth’s 35 km/s motion results in 20 arcsec aberration.  So, you should worry.

Comment: @eshaya 35km/s refers to Earth speed around the Sun, right? From Sun POV satellites that are orbiting Earth are orbiting Sun with close to the same speed.

Comment: Yes, the 35km/s refers to Earth’s motion around he Sun.  I brought it up for you to use to scale for other relative velocities in your project and decide their magnitudes.